Is it possible to find the average of a group of numbers and return the index of the number furthest from the average with one loop?
Specifically:
Write a function (in python, java or pseudocode) average(nums) that prints the mean of the numbers in list nums, and returns a tuple:

The tuple's first element is the index of the number furthest from the mean.
The tuple's second element is the number furthest from the mean.

Can this be done with one loop?
I know how to write the function with two loops, and using one or two loops are both O(n) time, so the code doesn't technically become more efficient with one loop. But I'm just curious if it can be done. A party trick, if you will.
Some of my thought process:
So computing the average as you iterate through the list is as simple as total += nums[i], then avg = total/(i+1). And I guess you could calculate which number is furthest from your current average, but by the time you get to the end of the list an extreme number could make your code incorrect , I think?

Is the number furthest from the mean not always either the maximum or the minimum? In that case, keep track of both and decide at the end which one of the two it is

Huh. I didn't think of that. I think you're right. I didn't expect it to be that simple. Thank you so much.

... and now ask for the number closest to the average.

@AcK Ok, I'm curious now. Do you think that would be possible with one loop?

Unlikely. The last value of the list can be arbitrarily large or small. So, within a limits of floating point range and precision, it can move the mean estimate by an arbitrary amount. Therefore you can not rule out any values as being nearest before reaching the end.

Similar: Concise way to get both min and max value of Java 8 stream


Is it possible to find the average of a group of numbers and return the index of the number furthest from the average with one loop?

Yes.  The number furthest from the mean will be either the largest or the smallest in the sample.  With a single pass through the data, you can compute the average and track the indices of the largest and smallest elements seen so far.  At the end, you'll know the indices of the overall largest and smallest.  You can check which of these is further from the mean, and return the information for that one.
